# How to render math formulas created with ckeditor5-math and displayed as HTML output containing math/tex script tags in another ckeditor

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I need help rendering math formulas created with CKEditor + an external library called ckeditor5-math. The issue is that when the formulas are displayed as HTML output, they contain math/tex script tags that are not rendered correctly using MathJax. It seems the backslash character is being treated as an escape character, causing the formulas to be displayed as plain text instead of rendered equations.

Here's an example of the generated output:

```
<p>Lorem... <script type="math/tex">x+\sqrt{1-x^2}</script> ...ipsum</p>
```

I would like to know how to correctly render these math formulas in another application that utilizes the same CKEditor mentioned above. Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Im using the library better-react-mathjax as a provider for parsing the formulas to be displayed.

I have been attempting to modify the configuration of the ckeditor5-math library component in the following way, but it hasn't been successful:

```
math: {
    engine: 'mathjax',
    lazyLoad: undefined,
    outputType: 'script',
    className: 'math-tex',
    forceOutputType: true,
    enablePreview: true,
    previewClassName: [],
    popupClassName: [],
    katexRenderOptions: {}
}
```

I am trying to configure the ckeditor5-math library to properly render math formulas using MathJax. However, despite adjusting the configuration as shown above, the issue persists. The formulas are still not rendering correctly in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried [CKEditor's online math editor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/math-equations.html). When in the console I try editor.getData() it returns:

For code [click here](https://codepen.io/Siddhant-Khanna-the-selector/pen/XWxoRMa)

```
<p>In elementary algebra, the <strong>quadratic formula</strong> is the solution of the quadratic equation.</p>
<p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow>
        <mo>-</mo>
        <mi>b</mi>
        <mo>±</mo>
        <msqrt>
          <msup>
            <mi>b</mi>
            <mn>2</mn>
          </msup>
          <mo>-</mo>
          <mn>4</mn>
          <mi>a</mi>
          <mi>c</mi>
        </msqrt>
      </mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mn>2</mn>
        <mi>a</mi>
      </mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </math></p>
<p><strong>Water is made from two elements</strong>: hydrogen and oxygen. If you put the two gases together, along with energy, you get water.</p>
<p><math class="wrs_chemistry" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mn>2</mn>
    <msub>
      <mi mathvariant="normal">H</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <mfenced>
      <mi mathvariant="normal">g</mi>
    </mfenced>
    <mo>+</mo>
    <msub>
      <mi mathvariant="normal">O</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <mfenced>
      <mi mathvariant="normal">g</mi>
    </mfenced>
    <mo>⇌</mo>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <msub>
      <mi mathvariant="normal">H</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <mi mathvariant="normal">O</mi>
    <mfenced>
      <mi mathvariant="normal">l</mi>
    </mfenced>
  </math></p>
<p>The entire formula for the surface area of a cylinder is <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mn>2</mn>
    <msup>
      <mi>πr</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msup>
    <mo>+</mo>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mi>πrh</mi>
  </math></p>
```